# the official MapFragment Xamarin example fails with "Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;"

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.android

I created a very basic project with just a simple map fragment (see below), imported the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps nuget, added a valid google api key and the correct permissions to my manifest, and it fails with the exception below

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

I get this UnhandledException when I start the app (I'm using a physical device - Galaxy S7 - to debug)

```
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
```

I tried to run the official Xamarin sample available [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/MapsAndLocationDemo_v3/) and I get the exact same problem when running the SimpleMapDemo project and selecting the option to load the mapfragment from a layout file.

I can display a MapFragment properly in another way more complex app so it doesn't look like a setup issue (missing sdk, etc). Actually, I ran into this issue while trying to reproduce in a simple app another problem I had in my complex app...

Any idea ?

Comment: do you have google play services in your android sdk ?

Comment: Yes of course. Actually, I was able to run google maps in another complex app but had other issues. it's while trying to reproduce them in a simple app that I run into this problem ... Also, not having the google play services sdk results in an helpful message kindly asking to install it ...

Comment: did you try clearing bin obj and a couple of rebuilds as i had a similar issue in the past which was solved when i did that

Comment: Yes, I saw this advice a lot while google issues with MapFragments. I've done that, to no avail. I also tried restarting VS (you never know ...)

Comment: Try using `class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead.

Comment: Any updates? Facing the same issue...